# Append function of Listmodel in qml is slow

Tags: listview, qml

I have problem with listview in qml, the component for delegate is row of many TextArea, then the ListModel will insert new row by calling : myListModel.append() function.

However, it takes 2-3 seconds to append new row, anyone have idea? ( If I replace the row item is many rectangles, it appends very fast).

I am using Qt 4.8, for some reasons, I can not use higher version. I also try using QAbstractListModel from C++ to expose to qml, the same result.
Thank you.
The main problem of code segment is below:

```
                ListModel{
                    id: targetModel
                }

                // the delegate for each target in the model
                Component{
                    id: listDelegate
                    Item {
                        id: delegateItem
                        width: listView.width
                        height: 30
                        clip: true

                        Row_input{ // this row contains many TextInput rectangle 

                        }
                ListView{
                    id: listView
                    anchors.rightMargin: 0
                    anchors.bottomMargin: -8
                    anchors.leftMargin: 0
                    anchors.topMargin: 0
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: 0
                    model: targetModel
                    delegate: listDelegate
                    interactive: false // not include mouse event to list view
                }

                Rectangle{
                    width: 30
                    height: 50
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                MouseArea{
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked:{
                       targetModel.append({})// append new row, it takes 2-3 seconds
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Please post some code describing the problem.

Comment: It's not `ListModel::append()` but your delegate `Row_input` that is slow. Can you show the code? Why does it have clipping enabled?

Comment: The Row_input contains many TextInput items, I also thought that the problem is the Row_input ( I test with many Rectangles items, it appends very fast). The clipping is no matter, I tried in both case enable and disable. I wonder that any solution in my case (many TextInput items on a row).

Comment: So, if the "many rectangles" work fast, it *is* the "Row_input" isn't it? How are we supposed to fix your problem - residing in the Row_input-code - when you won't show us the code of it?